# Is there a way to access and modify user data from system call in Minix 3? Can I use sys_datacopy() here? Why is my attempt not working?

Tags: linux, pointers, kernel, system-calls, minix

I want to implement a syscall in the PM server in Minix that has access to some data in the user space, and can modify it.

I am passing data to the syscall using Minix's message passing mechanism. In the `message` structure that is being passed, I assign one of the pointers to the address of the variable from the user space that I want to pass.

For example, in the user program,

```
message m;
m.m1_p1 = &var; //data to be passed
//pass it to the syscall
```

In the kernel, in the syscall function, I do

```
char *ptr = m_in.m1_p1;
```

However, when I try to either read or write the data, I get an error that the kernel has panicked, and needs a reboot.

I realise that this is probably because in user space, virtual addresses specific to the user are being used, which is not recognizable in the syscall.

On searching further, I found that Linux has functions [`copy_from_user()`](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re257.html) and [`copy_to_user()`](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re256.html) to achieve this.

Is there an equivalent of this is Minix? If not, is there any other way to achieve this?

---

With the help of [@osgx's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196561/osgx) suggestion in the comments, I have tried using `sys_datacopy()`. While this allows me to read and write the data in the system call, the changes I make are not reflected back into the user program that called the system call.

My latest attempt is as follows:

In the user program,

```
message m;
m.m1_p1 = &var; //data to be passed
printf("%c\n",*(m.m1_p1)); //gives the value in var
//pass it to the syscall
printf("%c\n",var); //gives the old value of var
```

Inside the syscall,

```
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
sys_datacopy(who_e,(vir_bytes)(m_in.m1_p1),SELF,(vir_bytes)(ptr),sizeof(char*)); //or some other version of sys_vircopy()?
printf("Read value of ptr : %c\n",*ptr); //gives correct value
*ptr = //new value
printf("New value of ptr : %c\n",*ptr); //gives modified value
```

Here, now I can access the value of `var` inside the syscall using `ptr`, and modify it inside the syscall as well. However, after returning from the syscall, I observe that the underlying value of `var' has not changed.

As per my understanding, what should have happened is that the `sys_datacopy()` should have copied an equivalent virtual of `m_in.m1_p1` that lies in the address space of the syscall to `ptr`, that points to the same physical address. So, `*ptr`should exactly reach `var`, thus modifying it.

Or is it that the data corresponding to the address is copied, when I use `sys_datacopy()`? If this is the case, one solution I can think of is defining a message structure that allows double pointers, and passing an `char**` to the syscall. Then, dereferencing once will ensure that the address is copied to `ptr`. But then again, dereferencing `ptr` will attempt to dereference a virtual address that belongs to the user process's address space, which will not work.

> Why is this method not working? What is the correct way to achieve this?

I am using Minix 3.2.1.

Thank you.

Comment: Can functions of `minix/include/minix/syslib.h` named `sys_datacopy` or `sys_copy` help you? datacopy [is used in VFS](http://code.metager.de/source/s?refs=sys_datacopy_wrapper&project=minix), possibly to implement `read` & `write` syscalls, here is the wrapper http://code.metager.de/source/xref/minix/minix/servers/vfs/utility.c#139. Also, are you sure to implement syscall in kernel, not in server? There are also sys_safecopyfrom / ..to / sys_vsafecopy listed at http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:kernelapi & http://condor.depaul.edu/glancast/443class/docs/lecOct05.html#slide21

Comment: @osgx Thank you. I came across these functions after I had posted this. They appeared highly relevant, but I could not find any example regarding their usage. I actually came across `SYS_SAFECOPYFROM` and `SYS_SAFECOPYTO`, which needed a grant id. I read about memory grants, but again, couldn't figure out how to implement them and couldn't find any examples either. I am implementing the syscall in a server. I am new to this, so sorry if I have used incorrect terms. What I assumed was that a syscall runs in kernel mode, especially when the kernel panicked when there was any error in there...

Comment: @osgx ... `sys_datacopy` seems very useful. But I am not able to understand its usage. Could you please direct me to, or provide an, example that would make this clearer? Thank you.

Comment: I'm don't understand anything of Minix & its <s>demons</s> services, but +50 rep is +50 rep. Did you try to start from some manual like "implementing syscall for minix"? Some manuals may have useful ideas of transmitting data and may mention sys_datacopy, sys_copy, sys_vsafecopy, sys_safecopyfrom. Another source of knowlendge is source of minix services in x-ref systems like metager.de

Comment: @osgx Thank you for your suggestions, I have tried them, and updated my question.

Comment: I cannot give you a closed solution but at last some thoughts: In kernel you do/might have access to the physical memory of your machine. Every process should have it's own mapping from virtual to physical memory address (kernel might have a mapping as well, but that would usually be 1:1). So you should at last be able to map an address by yourself by accessing the process memory map. Whatever functions you are looking for should do exactly that for you.

Comment: You should read [the documentation about grants (safecopies)](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:memorygrants) to see if it fits your use case.